# Entity Framework 6 code-first not creating all columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm creating a simple table using EF6 and code first. All the fields are created except for the `CreateDate` column. Why is that?

```
public class InspectionPoint
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

The `UpdateDate` field is being created as expected but not the `CreateDate`. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I **guess** it's because that field is read-only, since it only has a getter:

```
public class InspectionPoint
{
    // only has "get"ter - therefore it's readonly 
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; }      

    // Every other field has both "get" and "set" and can be set to new values
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is already pointed out by [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) it is a read-only property, and properties without a setter are not mapped by the Entity Framework. By doing this the Entity Framework is avoiding mapping properties that should not be mapped, such as computed properties.

A possible option is setting it with a `private` setter. This will enable the Entity Framework to see it as a read-write property and it will map it.

```
public class InspectionPoint
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; private set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

More information can be found on the following Microsoft documentation link: [Entity Framework Core Read-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#read-only-properties), which can provide a bit of insight into what is happening in the background.

Entity Framework Core also provides an easy approach to other alternatives that can be used such as [backing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations).

Additionally tested a simple console application with .NET Framework and Entity Framework 6, where a `private` setter is mapping the property.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works in EF Core. The author uses EF 6.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, thanks for the comment, I oversaw the EF6 mention and defaulted to Entity Framework Core. I also edited the answer with a more clear explanation.